# Shared Preferences not save data properly

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello I have 3 activities in my app and I transport data between them with Intent. The problem that I ran into is that Shared Preferences I have on my main activity get change when I returned to the main activity from the 3 activity. I suspect that the problem is that my intent get reboot but I'm not sure. I'm trying to get the data remain the same as it was when i moved to the 3 activity. my app start in activity 1 then its going to the main activity and at last if you click a button its goes to the third activity get some data and returned to the main activity the problem I have is that the data I got form the first activity get restart when I returned from the third activity. when i move data between activities I use intent.

my code to transport the intent activity 1:

```
        Bundle CIW = new Bundle();
    CIW.putInt("one", int1);
    CIW.putInt("two", int2);
    CIW.putDouble("double", double);
    Intent a = new Intent(Must.this, Main.class);
    a.putExtras(CIW);
    startActivity(a);
```

my code to get the bundles in my main activity (its in mine on create method):

```
            Intent must = getIntent();
        Intent name = getIntent();
        Bundle CIW = must.getExtras();
        Bundle card = name.getExtras();
        int1 = CIW.getInt("one");
        int2 = CIW.getInt("two");
        double= CIW.getDouble("double");
        int3 = card.getInt("three");
```

my Shared Preferences code (on pause):

```
            SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("one", Int1); //the rest of the variable 
editor.commit();
```

my Shared Preferences code (on resume):

```
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int1 = settings.getInt("one", int1); //the rest of the variable
```

my code to transport the intent activity 3:

```
Bundle number = new Bundle();
    number.putInt("three", int3);
    Intent a = new Intent(Card.this, Main.class);
    a.putExtras(number);
```

Comment: First of all, please don't use a Capital letter to start your variable names.  It makes your code hard to read.  As to your problem, it's hard to understand what your problem is.  Please edit your question to include expected result and what you actually get.  What do you mean by "restart" or "get changed" or "get reboot"?

Comment: did you forget to commit?

Comment: no I commit it just at the end

Answer (score 1):

Your shared preferences file (name) is always the same right?

If you are using shared preferences from different activity/services/intents/... you should use it with mode **MODE_MULTI_PROCESS** (constant value int = 4). If not, file gets locked and only one process can write it at once!

So when you call shared preferences in multi processes app do it like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("myapp",4);
```

MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is ON on all version till android 2.3, but latter must be called strictly! Offical docs say:

> Operating mode. Use 0 or MODE_PRIVATE for the default operation, MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE to control permissions. The bit MODE_MULTI_PROCESS can also be used if multiple processes are mutating the same SharedPreferences file. MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is always on in apps targetting Gingerbread (Android 2.3) and below, and off by default in later versions.